# Random numbers in a constructor of an object array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, random, constructor

Firstly, sorry if it's a silly question, but I have recently learn how to deal with classes.
My problem is that I've created a constructor which gives every data member a random number, with the following syntax:

```
#include <random>
```

...

```
//Constructor
cSystem::cSystem(void)
{
//Range of random numbers
double lower_bound = -100;
double upper_bound = 100;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(lower_bound,upper_bound);
std::default_random_engine re;

/*Initialization of data members*/
sMass=1.0014;
sPositionX= unif(re);
sPositionY= unif(re);
}
```

But then, I want to create an array of these "systems" in my main function

```
int main (void)
{
cSystem systems[numsist]; //numsist is a constant defined to be 1000

//Function that writes its characteristics in a file using a method that returns positions
getPositions(systems);

return 0;
}
```

But in the file, I just get

```
-73.6924    -8.26997
-73.6924    -8.26997
-73.6924    -8.26997
```

I thought that I was going through the constructor for every element of the array, giving it a different random value, but it seems like a single value is given at the beginning and then it is repeated throughout the vector.
What can I do to get a constructor that initializes every element in a random way?

Note: I also get the same values everytime I run the program, I suppose that the seed does not change, why is that the case?

Comment: But you're creating a new RNG in the constructor.  That'll produce the same series of random numbers.  Why don't you use a global RNG singleton?

Comment: Or just make `re` and `unif` `static` class members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that I've created a constructor which gives every data member a random number

- You are not seeding the PRNG when you make it default constructed. It will start with its default state every time.
- The PRNG is not supposed to be owned by any *one* class. It's expensive to seed it, and it is supposed to be shared by all functions (per thread) that needs to generate random numbers - so separate it from any classes.

I perfer to select a certain PRNG, but with the default, it could look like this:

```
std::default_random_engine& prng() {
    // seed only one PRNG per thread that needs is:
    static thread_local std::default_random_engine gen(std::random_device{}());
    return gen;
}
```

In every distribution function (member function or otherwise) you use in your program you may now call `prng()` to get the generator, seeded *once* and not *overseeded*.

Comment: It solves the problem of having the same number all over the array, which I'm very thankful for. However, the seed doesn't seem to change (as I mentioned in the "Note" part of my question), because I get the same values everytime I run the program. This program is a simulation of a galaxy, therefore, I would want to have different random initial positions of the solar systems in every run. I don't know how to use <random> very well, but maybe I could use srand(time(NULL)) and insert it into the seed that <random> uses, or maybe there's a not-so-intricate solution.

Comment: @A.D.EscañuelaCopado If the seed doesn't change (you can test it by printing it), you may need to add entropy yourself. Here's a half-hearted version: [portable seeding if buggy `random_device`s are taken into account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60723456/7582247). The third bullet in the second note applies to your case.

Comment: ... and no, I recommend that you don't go with `srand(time(NULL))`. You are on the right track with using `<random>`. It's better in every aspect.

Comment: @A.D.EscañuelaCopado You didn't actually test the example `prng()` in my answer, did you? I just noticed that you commented the same thing to the other answer, which does not contain any seeding at all, while mine does.

Comment: I tested both, and both "work" except for the change in seed, now I've updated my compiler to the latest version, in case that _that_ is the problem, since you said that "older versions of MinGW had a buggy implementation" in the post that you mentioned. However, I keep getting the same values, even for GCC 9.3.0 and using the c++17 flag.

Comment: I also tried the correction that you inserted in the [portable seeding if buggy random_devices are taken into account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721093/random-number-from-normal-distribution-in-c/60723456#60723456) post, but an error comes up: `'size' is not a member of 'std'`, and it happens in the `for(size_t s = 0; s < std::size(si);) {` line.

Comment: `std::size` is a C++17  function template. If you are using an older version, just replace `std::size` with the [old](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4108340/7582247) way of calculating the extent of arrays or use `std::extent<decltype(si)>::value`. Why not use C++17?

Comment: When using my example that is compensating for buggy MinGW implementations you can't possibly get the same seed every time - unless your `steady_clock` is broken too.

Comment: Do `std::cout << prng()() << '\n' << prng()() << '\n';` Are the values the same every time?

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks as my IDE in Windows 10 and I've implemented C++17, but I probably haven't done it correctly, that's why `std::size` doesn't work. I used to use Linux command line but my computer broke, so that's the only thing available right now. Regarding the `cout` of `prng()()`, I get a string of different values, but the string is the same everytime I run it. I'm happy to tell you that using `(sizeof(si)/sizeof(*si))` or `std::extent<decltype(si)>::value` makes it work :D. **Thank you a thousand times**

Answer (score 0):

You get the same values of `sPositionX` and `sPositionY` for each instance of `cSystem` since you are creating the `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>` and the `std::default_random_engine` every time the constructor is called.

You need to create them once and reuse them in the constructor. One way to do that would be to create class scoped `static` objects.

```
struct cSystem
{
   ...

   static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif;
   static std::default_random_engine re;
};
```

and just use them in the constructor.

Here's a complete program.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

struct cSystem
{
   cSystem();

   double sPositionX;
   double sPositionY;
   double sMass;

   static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif;
   static std::default_random_engine re;
};

std::uniform_real_distribution<double> cSystem::unif(-100, 100);
std::default_random_engine cSystem::re;

//Constructor
cSystem::cSystem()
{
   /*Initialization of data members*/
   sMass=1.0014;
   sPositionX= unif(re);
   sPositionY= unif(re);
}

void getPositions(cSystem* systems)
{
   for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
   {
      std::cout << systems[i].sPositionX << " " << systems[i].sPositionY << std::endl;
   }
}

int main (void)
{
   cSystem systems[3];

   getPositions(systems);

   return 0;
}
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/bS8E4u.

#### Update, in response to OP's comment.

You can initialize `re` as shown below to get different random numbers when the program is run again and again.

```
std::default_random_engine cSystem::re{std::random_device()()};
```

Comment: It solves the problem of having the same number all over the array, which I'm very thankful for. However, the seed doesn't seem to change (as I mentioned in the "Note" part of my question), because I get the same values everytime I run the program. This program is a simulation of a galaxy, therefore, I would want to have different random initial positions of the solar systems in every run. I don't know how to use <random> very well, but maybe I could use srand(time(NULL)) and insert it into the seed that <random> uses, or maybe there's a not-so-intricate solution.